# Extjs grid scrolls after store load

Tags: extjs, extjs4

how can I disable the "scroll to top" behavior of grid, after loading a store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the **[preserveScrollOnRefresh](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-cfg-preserveScrollOnRefresh)** property of the viewConfig.

```
viewConfig: {
    preserveScrollOnRefresh: true
}
```